# MPI_Bcast: Stack vs Heap

Tags: c++, mpi

I do not quite understand why I cannot broadcast an array that is stored in the heap (new double[n]), but it runs fine if the array is stored in the stack.
Please let me know what is going on.

```
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int iproc;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &iproc);

    int n = 1000;

    double *A=new double[n];
    //double A[n];                                                                                                       

    printf("Before Bcast from rank %d\n",iproc);
    MPI_Bcast(&A, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("After Bcast from rank %d\n",iproc);

    delete[] A;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before Bcast from rank 0
Before Bcast from rank 1
After Bcast from rank 0
After Bcast from rank 0  (why does this line show up again?)
APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Hangup (signal 1)
```

Comment: You are passing a reference to the `A` pointer to `MPI_Bcast` - did you mean to pass the pointer itself?

Comment: Indeed. It should have been A, as explained by Hiroki Kumazaki. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you should replace `&A` with `A`.

What happend in this case? A memory corruption.

`double *A` is resident on stack (A is in heap).
`MPI_Bcast(&A, n,,,)` will modify pointer itself and much more data on stack `int proc` and `int n` are victim of memory overwrite.

memory layout in stack is

```
double* A;  // it points some new address
int n;      // next to *A
int iproc;  // next to n
```

it is 16 bytes(in x86_64 environment)
`MPI_Bcast(&A, n,,` will write 0 for 40000 bytes from `&A`. that includes `&n` and `&iproc`.

It provides result with `A == n == iproc == 0`

So `delete[] A;` is forced to delete NULL pointer, it causes segfault.

to avoid these tragedy(shoot oneself in the foot)

```
const double *A = new double[n];
```

**const** will save you. in detail, see http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @RyanC.Robinson. If this answer is correct and sufficient, you should mark it as the accepted answer to give the author credit. Look for the checkmark under the voting icons on the left side of the answer.